# Please give hint: how to solve question below?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

This is a question from the IIT-JEE, an engineering entrance exam for admission into the Indian Institute of Technology.

> Let $\mathscr A$ be the set of all $3\times3$ symmetric matrices all of whose entries are either 0 or 1. Five of those entries are 1 and four of them are zero.
>
> 36. The number of matrices in $\mathscr A$ is
>     (A) 12
>     (B) 6
>     (C) 9
>     (D) 3

Comment: @Arthur I tried like this: since there will be 9 entries in the matrix and we have 5 1s and 4 0s therefore I evaluated permutation as 9P5 × 4P4 or 9P4×5P5 but how can we make two different cases for the same problem.

Comment: Find the positions of the zeros first.

Comment: @Muralidharan pls tell why 0s first not 1s

Comment: Because the number of zeros is even. Hence it either splits 2 in the upper triangle and 2 in the lower triangle or 2 on the diagonal and 1 each in the upper and lower triangles.

Comment: If you are preparing for JEE you can join us here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48921/discussions-in-pcm-and-anything-else

Answer (score 4):

So what do we need? We want the matrices to be symmetric, and contain five ones and four zeros.

There are two cases:

1) The diagonal consists of $1,0,0$ in some order, which can be decided in $3$ ways. The rest of the elements are four ones and two zeros. Now, these can be permuted amongst themselves in three ways, since deciding the top three decides the bottom three, and the top three elements consists of two ones and one zero. Hence, the answer here is $3 \times 3=9$.

2) The diagonal consists of $1,1,1$ (which can't be permuted). The rest of the elements are four zeros and two ones. Now, these can be permuted amongst themselves in three ways, since deciding the top three decides the bottom three, and the top three elements consists of two zeros and one one. Hence, the answer here is $3 \times 1=3$.

In total, we have $9+3=12$ such matrices. Since you are doing the IITJEE, which is a very time tight exam, you can do the first step and directly write $12$ as the answer, since it has to be bigger than $9$ by the first step.